# multilineTextAlignment doesn't work on ScrollView - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, iphone, swiftui, scrollview, text-alignment

I am doing a calculator app and I want to align the TextField inside the ScrollView to the right of the screen.

What I want but without using ScrollView:
[image: Code 1 image]
[image: Interface 1 image]

What I have by now (multilineTextAlignment(.trailing) doens't work here):
[image: Code 2 image]
[image: Interface 2 image]

Any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the desired outcome with this. By using an `HStack` and a `Spacer()` we can push any text you want to the right side of the screen.

```
VStack {
        ScrollView {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("123456")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    .font(.custom("Arial", size: 80))
            }
                
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a good idea, and a part of the issue is arranged. With this solution I have achieved to move the TextField to the right side of the screen. But the problem is that it doesn't work like a "multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)", because the String is still being written to the right side.